# SQL server - how does adding identity column in existing table works internally?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, architecture, identity-column

I have a table with 100 rows, but my primary key column is not with identity property.(but values of this column seems like identity column and sequential: 1-100)
Now i tried to add new identity column with below code

```
alter table tableA add new_Iden_col bigint identity(1,1)
```

but i find that the new column identity values are not in sorted order as per my primary key column.

[my output of old Primary key col and new inserted identity column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKIqS.png)

So can someone explain me why the newly added column is not same as my primary key column even though my old column values are populated naturally in same way and not dynamically sorted for output.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: First of all who cares? You should not be concerned with what row gets what value. Second I suspect it is likely to be in the "order" of your clustered index. What is the ddl for your table without the identity column?

Comment: It matters onwhich row gets which value for this situation, because I'm trying to make the existing primary key column (without idenTity) to have identity property. So when i tried to add new identity column its populating values not in same order of my primary key values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IDENTITY` function can be used to create a new `IDENTITY` column and assign incremental values in the sequence specified by the `ORDER BY` clause of `SELECT...INTO`.  Below is an example creates a new `IDENTITY` column for use as a new primary key from the old primary key column order.

```
SELECT 
    IDENTITY(bigint, 1,1) AS new_Ident_col
  , OtherData
INTO FROM dbo.TableA_New
FROM dbo.TableA
ORDER BY old_PK_col;

DROP TABLE dbo.TableA;

EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.TableA_New', 'TableA';

ALTER TABLE dbo.TableA ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TableA PRIMARY KEY(new_Ident_col);
```

Comment: **Thanks Dan,** more than getting this situation resolved, i'd like to know on what basis the SQL engine assigns number to my table as explained and shown in my output. i'd like to understand that logic intentionally.

Comment: @Hemanth, I would expect SQL Server to assign the values in order of the clustered index, or in the case of a heap, allocation order.  However, I suggest one avoid relying on undocumented behavior upon since it may change depending on SQL version and patch level.

Comment: **Thank you Dan**, it helped.
Yes will do that way.